# Run apache in both host machine and docker container on 80 port

Tags: apache, docker, reverse-proxy, portforwarding

I need to setup something like automated server setup using docker. Now server machine should support both docker or normal setups. So I need to setup apache web server on both docker container and host machine on 80 port. Like

```
Host Machine  : application1.serverhost.com
Docker Machine  : application2.serverdocker.com
```

But Docker will not utilize 80 port as it is already bind on host machine apache. While I am thinking of use reverse proxy on host machine with apache like

```
Proxy Setting -> 172.17.0.2:8080
```

while on browser connect to proxy `application2.serverdocker.com` on 80 port. IP -> 172.17.0.2 is docker container IP which I am thinking to get from docker inspect.

But if any other way to handle this in docker itself where I can ignore reverse proxy on host machine. And call both `application1.serverhost.com` and `application2.serverdocker.com` from browser without appending port.

EDIT : One big issue using reverse proxy is that whenever I need to add another docker on same server I need to add also proxy for that new IP too as that would also running docker apache on other port like 8081 than Host port:80 and first docker's port:8080. In other words lot of reverse proxy settings and ports in case of lot of docker instances.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a [reverse proxy, (like an NGiNX)](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/), that means both your Apache servers must run on ports different from 80.

Only your NGiNX would run (on host directly for instance) on port 80, and would redirect to `localhost_apache1:xxx` and `172.17.0.2_apache2:yyy`.

From the user perspective, both Apache would be seen "as if" they were running on port 80 themselves.

Comment: Well I do not need nginx as I can setup host machine apache as reverse proxy using proxy module. In this case only docker need to run and connect to proxy, Other host domain may run normally on host apache. Anyway question still exits if other approach can be used ?

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj I guess you can indeed use one apache to reverse proxy to the other. But to the question "is there another approach?": my answer still stands (to clearly separate the roles provided by each web servers)

Comment: I'll back up VonC's answer. reverse proxy is the way to do this. I've done the same thing on OSX as the host. Host is running apache on port 80, also have apache running in a container (in docker-machine) running on port 80. Just need to set up reverse proxy on the host to proxy http://<host>/proxypath to the docker-machine IP.